# Magento 2: Sorting is not working while adding custom column in Order Grid Using Ui Component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to add a custom column in order grid with sorting enabled in it.

For now, I am including a column which shows the color attribute of the product in that order.

This is the file **sales_order_grid.xml** file created in `app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/ui_component/`

below is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="color" class="VENDOR\MODULE\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Color">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Color</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
</listing>
```

And app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Color.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
class Color extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\OrderFactory
 */
protected $_orderFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
 */
protected $productFactory;

/**
 * 
 * @param ContextInterface   $context           
 * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory   
 * @param array              $components        
 * @param array              $data              
 */
public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
}

/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            //Get order details by order id.
            $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($item['entity_id']);

            //Get all products in this order.
            $products = $order->getAllItems();
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $productId = $product->getProductId();
                $productData = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productId);
                $item['color'] = $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData);
            }
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
}
```

Now when I perform sorting over this it gives following as color column is not related to order:

```
2 exception(s): Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'color' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` ORDER BY color ASC  LIMIT 20 Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'color' in 'order clause'

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'color' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` ORDER BY color ASC  LIMIT 20
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
```

Same case when applying a filter, so how to perform this.

Comment: http://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/magento/A/question/182146.html

Comment: look at it may be this could be great help for you

Answer (score 0):

Override "Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection.php" and then need to create below code in that file.

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        //do your sql join like below code
        /*$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('secondTable')],
            'main_table.entity_id = secondTable.entity_id',
            array('*')
        );*/
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the magento is looking for 'color' column in `sales_order` table which it cannot find.

You will have to either provide custom `dataprovider` for the column or append these values in the respective rows of the table after adding a new 'color' column.

Answer (score 0):

protected function _initSelect()
{
parent::_initSelect();

```
    //do your sql join like below code
    /*$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('secondTable')],
        'main_table.entity_id = secondTable.entity_id',
        array('*')
    );*/
}
0
```

Override "Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection.php" and then need to create below code in that file.